# Get a function declaration from another llvm::Module

Tags: llvm, codegen

In my application i have 2 LLVM modules - the runtime one (which contains `void foo(int * a)` function definition) and executable one (which i'm creating using LLVM C++ API).

In my executable module i create `int main(int argc, char ** argv)` and want to put `llvm::CallInst` into it's body, which would call `foo()` function from runtime module.

Here is my code:

```
Function * fooF = Function::Create(runtimeModule->getFunction("foo")->getFunctionType(),
    GlobalValue::WeakAnyLinkage, "foo", execModule);
```

After that, i link two modules together:

```
Linker linker("blabla", execModule, false);
linker.LinkInFile("/path/to/runtime.bc", false);
execModule = linker.releaseModule();
```

This compiles OK, however when i run Verifier pass on linked module i get:

```
Global is external, but doesn't have external or dllimport or weak linkage!
void (%i32*)* @foo
invalid linkage type for function declaration
void (%i32*)* @foo
```

It's worth mentioning, that all globals in runtime module are internalized using Internalize pass. After linking, but before running Verifier, i'm running Dead Global Elimination pass amongst some other optimizations. And when i do `dump()` on resulting module, i see, that `@foo` which is coming from runtime module gets removed too, despite it's used by `main()`. It seems, LLVM thinks that `@foo` definition in runtime and `@foo` declaration in executable are unrelated.

I've tried to play with linkage types - no luck.

So, what is the right way to create a call to the function from another module?

Comment: Quick q: do these two Modules share the same context?

Comment: What is context? LLVMContext? Dunno then.

Comment: The types are "compatible" only within the same context. Make sure your modules share them. Check http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1LLVMContext.html for more info.

Comment: Yes, they are sharing same context - i get it by getGlobalContext().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i've fixed it, but i still can't understand what was the problem. During building of my runtime bitcode module, i've been applying internalize transformation on it. So i tried to do this at run-time after linking and it helped me.

Ah, and i've been using `GlobalValue::WeakAnyLinkage`.